# Large scale deletions from STL vector crashing my binary

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, crash, g++

My binary is crashing. On running the core dump, I found the following :

```
#0  0x00a6a363 in memmove () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x083a108c in std::__copy_trivial<piola::piolaOrderBook*> (__first=0xb277f2c4, __last=0xb277f2bc, __result=0xb277f2c0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:258
258           std::memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * (__last - __first));
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x083a0ad6 in std::__copy_aux2<piola::piolaOrderBook*> (__first=0xb277f2c4, __last=0xb277f2bc, __result=0xb277f2c0)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:279
279         { return std::__copy_trivial(__first, __last, __result); }
(gdb) frame 3
#3  0x083a02d1 in std::__copy_ni2<piola::piolaOrderBook**, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<piola::piolaOrderBook**, std::vector<piola::piolaOrderBook*, std::allocator<emapi::EmapiOrderBook*> > > > (__first=0xb277f2c4, __last=0xb277f2bc, __result=
      {_M_current = 0xb277f2c0})
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:296
296           return _OutputIterator(std::__copy_aux2(__first, __last, __result.base(),
(gdb) frame 4
#4  0x0839f1b0 in std::__copy_ni1<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<piola::piolaOrderBook**, std::vector<piola::piolaOrderBook*, std::allocator<piola::piolaOrderBook*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<piola::piolaOrderBook**, std::vector<piola::piolaOrderBook*, std::allocator<piola::piolaOrderBook*> > > > (__first={_M_current = 0xb277f2c4}, __last=
      {_M_current = 0xb277f2bc}, __result={_M_current = 0xb277f2c0})
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:317
317           return std::__copy_ni2(__first.base(), __last.base(),
(gdb) frame 5
#5  0x0839d676 in std::copy<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<piola::piolaOrderBook**, std::vector<piola::piolaOrderBook*, std::allocator<piola::piolaOrderBook*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<piola::piolaOrderBook**, std::vector<piola::piolaOrderBook*, std::allocator<piola::piolaOrderBook*> > > > (__first={_M_current = 0xb277f2c4}, __last={_M_current = 0xb277f2bc},
    __result={_M_current = 0xb277f2c0})
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:358
358            return std::__copy_ni1(__first, __last, __result, __Normal());
(gdb)
```

Most of this is cryptic to me, however on looking up memmove it seems like the code crashed because it could not handle the deletions from the vector (since deleting from a vector is a very heavy operation for large vectors) ?

Am I correct ? If yes, how can I fix this issue (apart from fixing the design of course) ?

The code is here :

```
for (orderbkIterator = vOrderBook.begin(); orderbkIterator != vOrderBook.end(); orderbkIterator++)
    {

        if (  (*(*orderbkIterator)->getOrderBookId()) == *(TradableInst->getOrderBookId()) )
        {
            long long a = (*(*orderbkIterator)->getOrderBookId());
            ADDVLOG(LOG_INFO, "Removing record (%lld) from vOrderBook", a );
            vOrderBook.erase(orderbkIterator);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: The *real* memory corruption probably happened nowhere near this operation.  Run your program under `valgrind` and fix the *very first* problem it reports.  Repeat until it doesn't complain.

Comment: ... Actually now you've posted the code: doesn't `erase` invalidate vector iterators?  (I can't remember offhand.)

Comment: You're incrementing an invalid iterator whenever the `if' statement executes.

Comment: @Zack holy crap, i think you are right !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`std::vector::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

> **Iterators and references to the erased elements and to the elements between them and the end of the container are invalidated**. Past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

so `orderbkIterator` will be invalid when next incremented if the `erase()` was called. Change the structure of the loop as `erase()` returns the next iterator after the iterator that was removed, meaning only increment if an `erase()` did not happen:

```
for (orderbkIterator = vOrderBook.begin(); orderbkIterator != vOrderBook.end();)
{
    if (...)
    {
        orderbkIterator = vOrderBook.erase(orderbkIterator);
    }
    else
    {
        ++orderbkIterator;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that

```
vOrderBook.erase(orderbkIterator);
```

will invalidate the iterator. Continuing the increment it will lead to undefined results.

Answer (score 0):

The remove erase idiom will prevent many of the pitfalls with invalidated iterators.

Rewritting the loop using this idiom would look something like the following:

```
vOrderBook.erase(
  std::remove_if(vOrderBook.begin(), vOrderBook.end(), <unary-predicate>),
  vOrderBook.end());
```

The *unary-predicate* could be a lambda or a functor.